# Conflict on Internet Explorer 11 using webforms C# and ajax control toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Good afternoon,

I'm using C# webforms framework 4.0 with visual studio 2015 with ajax control toolkit and trying to use webcam.js to capture images from my webcam and I'm having problems with Internet Explorer 11.
I modified the parts in the html file that is using jquery so it will only use javascript and html5. (It opens a tag   in the execution time).
My guess is ajax control toolkit is not compatible with .swf file (flash file), but besides this, Im having the following errors:

- JavaScript critical error at line 332, column 5 in http://localhost:6396/Js/LOG/webcam.js\n\nSCRIPT1010:  Identificator expected
  -In the line: var shutter = new Audio();   ===>Error: 0x800a1391 -  'Audio' is not defined
- 0x800a1391 - 'Webcam' is not defined (even though it is defined in webcam.js)

The link for webcam.js is  https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

---> The usage if fine with chrome and firefox.

---> Utilized components and libraries:

```
Menu.ascx TagName="Menu" TagPrefix="swa" 
jquery-1.9.1.js
jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js
jquery.multiselect.js
TagName="BOOSTAjaxLoad" TagPrefix="uc3"
BOOSTCtrls  TagPrefix="BC1"
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" (in the masterpage)
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc2"
TagName="EntityFromUser" TagPrefix="uc2"



<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<uc2:EntityFromUser></uc2:EntityFromUser>
<cc2:MaskedEditExtender></cc2:MaskedEditExtender>
<cc2:CalendarExtender> </cc2:CalendarExtender> 
<BC1:BOOSTButton></BC1:BOOSTButton>
<uc3:BOOSTAjaxLoad></uc3:BOOSTAjaxLoad>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It will be easier for others to help you if you can include a minimal complete example of your code within the question itself (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Clearly GitHub is the first place you should go https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues